# Seeder already exists in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I migrated the table. Also, I created a seeder and using DB class to seed it. However, I am getting an error `Seeder already exists`. I used `php artisan clear-compiled`,
`composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan optimize` before running it. Please help me.

Comment: Have you recently written a new seeder? If so then did you copy it from old one and maybe forgot to change class name?

Comment: Yes I wrote it for the first time. I don't do what you said. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

if i will run php artian make:seed TestSeeder and TestSeeder class or file already created in seeds/ folder then this error will occur Seeder already exists in Laravel.
Remove old file in seeds/ folder and make new seeder .